# Time Complexity - Bidirectional Dijkstra

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dijkstra, bidirectional

I want to know the time-complexity of a bidirectional Dijkstra algorithm.

A normal Dijkstra using a Min-Heap has `O(n log n + m)`. My guess would be that the Bidirectional stays same. However [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search) suggests 
that the improvement of Bidirectional Search in general can be expressed in O-Notation.

Is this possible to calculate for the bidirectional Dijkstra as well and how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically the bidirectional approach cost twice the monodirectional processing of a half-sized graph . For brute-force exponential algorithms that's a huge gain (from O(m<sup>n</sup>) to O(2*(m<sup>n/2</sup>)).
For Djikstra, the worst case remains basically the same.

However, time complexity is maybe not the best metric to assess efficiency here.

In practical cases like finding a route on a road network, bidirectional approach is akin to growing a disc around each end and stop (nearly) as soon as both discs meet, while a single-direction approach would require to grow a disc from the start until you reach the end.

Intuitively, if R is the straight distance between start and end, the cost of a straigth search would be O(R<sup>2</sup>), while the bidirectional approach would be in O(2*(R/2)<sup>2</sup>), i.e. 2 times faster.

[this paper](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr06/cos423/Handouts/EPP%20shortest%20path%20algorithms.pdf) covers the topic pretty well.

And at any rate, A* is basically the way to go unless you're exploring a search space where no efficient estimate heuristic is available.

Comment: Great answer. I am mainly using it for Road - Networks where I indeed use A-Star or if I have the change to do some preprocessing: Contraction Hierarchies.

Comment: I only used A* in computing challenges or video-game-ish code so far, and I found the birirectional approach much too bulky to implement. There are other ways to improve time efficiency, notably by adding a tie-breaker to the estimate distance heuristic (when moving on tiles where many equivalent paths are available) or, like the paper I refered to explains, adding carefully chosen helper waypoints or precomputing shortcuts.